# Calculate Direction of vector on 3D

Tags: math, vector

I want to know the theory of calculating direction of vector.

For example, I would like to make P2 follow P1 right behind and P1 is moves around Z.

[image: example picture]

Let's P1 is not going Negative Z, so P1 would have cases:`(+, +, +), (+, -, +), (-, -, +), (-, +, +).`

On this case, I can calculate scalar, but cannot calculate P2's direction.

For example, I just calculate P1 and P2's coordinates, and put P2 with the result, P2 could go front of P1 not behind.

So I wonder how can I calculate vector direction?

I want to know the 'theory'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. What do you mean by " P2 could go front" or "behind" ?

Comment: @MBo I mean, I want to let P1 is watching Z-coordinate and P2 always behind P1 ( P2 watching P1's back ).

But if I just calculate P2 and P1 like scalar( cause I don't know how to calculate through vector ), P2 is not positioning where I want.

Comment: Sometimes, in coordinates with positive or negative, P2 is watching P1s forehead, not back. I want to know how calculate P1's behind coordinates.

With Positive coordinates, P1's behind should be +, and the other case, P1's behind should be -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with:

Let P1 move around Z-axis, and it's position is (w is angular velocity)

```
Z1 = Z0
X1 = R * Cos(w * t)
Y1 = R * Sin(w * t)
```

Starting position for P2 is

```
Z2 = Z0 // the same height, so later Z-component is not considered, vz = 0
X2 = 2 * R
Y2 = 0
```

At every step we should calculate P1 position and give P2 some shift to follow P1.

```
dx = X1 - X2
dy = Y1 - Y2
vx = dx * C
vy = dy * C
X2 = X2 + vx * dt
Y2 = Y2 + vy * dt
```

here `dt` is time interval between calculations, C is some velocity - or constant, or depending on distance with some limitations.

v(vx, vy, vz) is vector pointing from current P2 position to the current P1 position.

Comment: Thanks. If also z is moving, I need to just calculate Z = R * tan(w * t) , Z2 = Z, dz = Z1 - Z2, vz = dz * C, Z2 = Z2 + vz * dt. right?

Comment: Yes, it looks right. But note that tan changes quickly and with breaks

Comment: You mean I need to warn about -Pi/2 -n*Pi < z < Pi/2 +n*Pi, right?

Comment: No, Pi is related to argument of tangent but Z values will go to infinity near w*t=Pi/2+Pi*N. I just want to warn that tan formula with unlimited argument might cause unwanted effects